# auto-detect and auto-embed youtube videos. PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, youtube

I run a 4chan style imageboard. When users post youtube or soundcloud links, I would like for the board to give a second link which, when clicked, would embed the video.

If I am not mistaken, 4chan uses JS to accomplish this. I have also seen many forum admins using php to do this. I know that wordpress uses php to do this.

If I went with php, I was thinking of going with something based on this:
https://www.warpconduit.net/2013/04/13/automatically-embedding-video-using-only-the-url-with-the-help-of-oembed/

For JS I am not entirely sure how to go about it. I would probably use a regex to detect youtube urls and then convert that information to an embed

Comment: I don't know or care a what a 4chan imageboard is but why add a second link? Is it like a captcha before allowing embed into post? Why cant your code just detect the link and do an embed from that all by itself when user clicks "post"? I hope my answer is useful anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need RegEx, PHP or oEmbed to do this. Both sites allow **iFrame embeds**. So when a user gives a link just add the iframe embedding part yourself (around their link) and output that as part of the user's post.

Use String functions like `indexOf` to see if the link contains the word "soundcloud" or "youtube" then adjust user's given link to correct format for the iframe embedding.

Some examples:

**Youtube :** format = `youtube.com/embed/` + User Link

User puts `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKE0Py64jmk` so your code makes it as...

```
<iframe width="500" height="300"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KKE0Py64jmk">
</iframe>
```

**SoundCloud :** format = `w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=` + User Link

User puts `https://soundcloud.com/thenextmen/sofa-feat-pupajim` then your code changes it to...

```
<iframe width="500" height="300"
src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/thenextmen/sofa-feat-pupajim">
</iframe>
```

Comment: So if I have a website with 10.000.000 members, which 500.000 of them have a youtube link in their bio, am I going to have to go and embed every single one manually?